# Google Maps directions text

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making an Android app that provides directions from the current location. I want to know if there is any way to obtain the directions as text from the Google Maps. I do not need to display the map or draw a polyline. Only the directions have to be displayed as text. For example:

```
1. Turn left at XYZ street.
2. Go straight for 500 metres.
etc. etc.
```

I know that it is possible to use JSON and obtain the information required to display the directions on a map. However, this does not provide word directions. Can Google Maps API v2 be used for this? If not, how can the directions be obtained as text?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally figured out a way to do this.
The url http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json returns the direction information in the JSON format. One of the key-value pairs has the key `"html_instructions"`. The value for this can be retrieved and used for the directions as text.

Comment: can you share how you did that?

Comment: @smitkpatel You can use `Html.fromHtml(steps.getInstructions()).toString();` to convert the      `"html_instuctions"` response into readable format.